# Using cURL to send SMTP emails on Linux, headers shown in body

Tags: email, curl, header, smtp

I'm trying to develop an email alert system for an application I've put together. I'm using cURL to send emails through an existing SMTP server like so:

```
curl smtp://x.x.x.x --mail-from sender@example.com --mail-rcpt recipient@example.com --upload-file curlmail.txt
```

Curlmail.txt has the following data:

```
From: sender@example.com
To: recipient.example.com
Subject: This is a test email

Test
```

My problem is that email headers seem to be sending in the body. i.e the following result:
[im too new for embeding pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raY8K.png)

I want to use curl over any other methods as it seems to be the best for my use case- I'm implementing this on a couple of different servers where MailX or sendMail may not work as intended- or work differently. Regardless, any help or advice is greatly appreciated- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some parameter, as the port, the user and the <> on the curlmail.txt email addresses. Try this:

```
curl --ssl-reqd smtp://x.x.x.x:587 --mail-from sender@example.com --mail-rcpt recipient@example.com --user 'sender@example.com:sender_password' --upload-file curlmail.txt
```

The parameter `--ssl-reqd` is requires only if you need to use a SSL connection.

587 is the port number. Please use the correct port number for your server.

Add the sender `--user` and his password. Please note that the user could be the simple name or the username@domain.com

Then on your curlmail.txt file you should use this header

```
From: "sender_name" <sender@example.com>
To: "recipient_name" <recipient.example.com>
Subject: This is a test email

Test
```